# Run php script from command line endless

Tags: php

I have a file named `/root/folder/myfile.php` that will handle incoming packets from a specific port by a GPS device.

When I use `[root@main ~] php /root/folder/myfile.php`, everything works fine.

I need this file run every second to listen.

I researched for a while and figured out that using `php cli` is a solution, so I tried above command but as long as the shell is open (I'm using PUTTY), file is executing and when I close the shell, process will be killed.

How can I (where can I) add a command that will run this file every second, or may be in realtime?

I'm using linux centOS 6.5.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nohup php myscript.php &
```

the `&` puts your process in the background.
The solution from [Run php script as daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036654/run-php-script-as-daemon-process)
To kill it:
1) display all running proceses with: `ps aux | less` or `top` command
2) find pid(process id) and kill with: `kill pid`

Comment: Thanks again. When I use this it's says  `ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'`!!! Why is that?

Comment: that's pretty obvious message. try this:
nohup php myscript.php </dev/null &>/dev/null &

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the `cron` functionality of your server.

Similar to this maybe:

[running a script from cron every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606095/running-a-script-from-cron-every-second)